# what happens to workflows running on Sharepoint 2010 WFE when an IIS reset occurs?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

I have a few sharepoint 2010 workflow questions:

1. if there are running workflows on a sharepoint 2010 WFE and an IIS reset occurs will it force new workflows to be run on a different WFE?  what about workflow timer job reset?
2. does a workflow timer job reset kill the workflow currently running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. When you reset IIS you restart w3wp.exe process. Workflows run in
   different process (owstimer.exe) so your workflows continuing run
   without any problem.
2. If you end task owstimer.exe process, workflows stop to run and will
   be run again in the next time as is setting.